When algebra isomorphism must preserve involution
Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra where $K$ is a field with a unique ordering.
We say involution $*$ is positive, if the map $A \to K$ via $a \mapsto tr(a^*a)$ is positive definite with respect to the ordering. Here, $tr(a)$ is the trace of the left multiplication map $a:x \mapsto ax$.
Suppose there is a $K$-algebra isomorphism $$\varphi: A \to B.$$
If there is a unique (up to isomorphism) positive involution in $A$ and $B$, can we say the involution must be preserved by the isomorphism $\varphi$: $$\varphi: (A, *_A) \to (B, *_B)?$$

Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/478875/6518
